# Convert the value of ASP.NET Gridview1.FindControl("Amount").text; Value to Float

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview

How can I convert the value of ASP.NET `((TextBox)Gridview1Row.FindControl("Amount")).text` of its value to `Float`.

```
foreach (GridViewRow Gridview1Row in Gridview1.Rows)
{            
DataRow OneDataRow;

OneDataRow["Amount"]= ((TextBox)Gridview1Row.FindControl("Amount")).text  //Need to convert to float
}
```

I'm having incorrect datatype format.
I tried `float.Parse` and `(float)` and still having an error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you debug your code and check what are you getting from `((TextBox)Gridview1Row.FindControl("Amount")).text`?

Comment: I debugged it and entered numeric value. During debug mode the value on the textbox control inside the Gridview was numeric.

Comment: I also tried this TextBox txtAmount = ((TextBox)rRow.FindControl("Amount"));

                            Amount = float.Parse(txtAmount.Text);
                            OneDataRow["Amount"] = Amount;     but still getting an error of "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: @gwiyaomingyaoming string amountStr = ((TextBox)rRow.FindControl("Amount")).Text;
Amount = float.Parse(amountStr); OneDataRow["Amount"] = Amount; try this and make sure the input you get is numeric

Comment: Did you check the value of `txtAmount.Text` while debugging? is it the same value you entered in the UI?

Comment: For the record this following codes work:  
TextBox txtAmount = ((TextBox)rRow.FindControl("Amount")); 
Amount = float.Parse(txtAmount.Text); 
OneDataRow["Amount"] = Amount;

string amountStr = ((TextBox)rRow.FindControl("Amount")).Text; Amount = float.Parse(amountStr); OneDataRow["Amount"] = Amount;


Found out the issue was the existing Null value on the Amount Column of the table.
I just applied some condition on the null value of the Float datatype to cleanse it.

Thank you guys! Cheers